# Replacement for deprecated NEST codes

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

I have updated NEST.dll to 5.5.0 and some classes are no longer available. Is there a documentation to check what is the replacement for these or is someone familiar what can be used to replace them? I updated the dll since it was needed when I upgraded to ES version 5.3.

Nest.DateRange.From

Nest.DateRange.To

Nest.BoolFilterDescriptor

Nest.RangeFilterDescriptor

Nest.FilteredQueryDescriptor

BoolQueryDescriptor

Nest.CustomScoreQueryDescriptor

Nest.FilterContainer

Nest.Filter

Nest.Range

Nest.IndexNameMarker

Nest.TypeNameMarker

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at

- [NEST 2.x release post](https://www.elastic.co/blog/ga-release-of-nest-2-0-our-dot-net-client-for-elasticsearch) that details high level changes from 1.x to 2.x (you mention filters, so you must be upgrading from Elasticsearch 1.x)
- [NEST 1.x -> 2.x breaking changes](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/2.x/breaking-changes.html)
- [NEST 5.x release post](https://www.elastic.co/blog/nest-5-0-released) that details high level changes from 2.x to 5.x
- [NEST 2.x -> 5.x breaking changes](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/current/_breaking_changes.html)

for all `*FilterDescriptor`, you should use `*QueryDescriptor` equivalents and execute them in a filter context, for example, [in the `filter` clause of a `bool` query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/current/bool-queries.html#unary-plus-operator).

> Nest.DateRange.From
>
> Nest.DateRange.To

`Nest.DateRange` is used for the [`date_range` datatype](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/range.html); if you want to do a `range` query on `date` fields, you can [use `DateRange(...)` query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/current/date-range-query-usage.html).

> Nest.IndexNameMarker

Equivalent is `IndexName`

> Nest.TypeNameMarker

Equivalent is `TypeName`